# Filters not working in Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have the following mapping and settings for an index:

```
def init_index():
    ES_CLIENT.indices.create(
        index = "social_media",
        body = {
            "settings": {
                "index": {
                    "number_of_shards": 3,
                    "number_of_replicas": 0
                },
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "my_english": {
                            "type": "standard",
                            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "asciifolding",
                                "cust_stop",
                                "my_snow"
                            ]
                        },
                        "my_english_shingle": {
                            "type": "standard",
                            "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                            "filter": [
                                "lowercase",
                                "asciifolding",
                                "cust_stop",
                                "my_snow",
                                "shingle_filter"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "filter": {
                        "cust_stop": {
                            "type": "stop",
                            "stopwords_path": "stoplist.txt",
                        },
                        "shingle_filter" : {
                            "type" : "shingle",
                            "min_shingle_size" : 2,
                            "max_shingle_size" : 2,
                            "output_unigrams": True
                        },
                        "my_snow" : {
                            "type" : "snowball",
                            "language" : "English"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )

    press_mapping = {
        "tweet": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
                "_id": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": True,
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                },
                "text": {
                    "type": "multi_field",
                    "fields": {
                        "text": {
                            "include_in_all": False,
                            "type": "string",
                            "store": False,
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        },
                        "_analyzed": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "store": True,
                            "index": "analyzed",
                            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                            "analyzer": "my_english"
                        },
                        "_analyzed_shingles": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "store": True,
                            "index": "analyzed",
                            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                            "analyzer": "my_english_shingle"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    constants.ES_CLIENT.indices.put_mapping (
        index = "social_media",
        doc_type = "tweet",
        body = press_mapping
    )
```

I notice that except `lowercase` no other filter is working. The termvectors for both the analyzers are same since `shingle_filter` is also not working.

`GET /social_media/_analyze?analyzer=my_english_shingle&text=complaining when` should remove `when`, stem `complaining` to `complain` and return a shingle `complain _` but instead it gives me:

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "complaining",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 11,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "when",
         "start_offset": 12,
         "end_offset": 16,
         "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

What could be the reason??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to define new [custom analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) and not new [standard analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) you need to change the types in the mapping of both your analyzers from `standard` to `custom`. Standard analyzers actually don't take any of the settings you are passing in the mapping - personally would prefer ES to throw an exception in such a case but instead he is just creating new standard analyzers with no custom fields and ignores everything else you passed in (try removing `lowercase` form both your analyzers and re-run your analyzer, the output will still be lowercased!):

```
"analyzer": {
  "my_english": {
    "type": "custom", // <--- CUSTOM
    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
    "filter": [
      "lowercase",
      "asciifolding",
      "stop",
      "my_snow"
    ]
  },
  "my_english_shingle": {
    "type": "custom", // <--- CUSTOM
    "tokenizer": "whitespace",
    "filter": [
      "lowercase",
      "asciifolding",
      "stop",
      "my_snow",
      "shingle_filter"
    ]
}
```

With this the query (I changed the query and the custom stop words to just `stop` as I don't have your file) `GET /social_media/_analyze?analyzer=my_english_shingle&text=COMPLAINING TEST` returns:

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "complain",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 11,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "complain test",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 16,
         "type": "shingle",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "test",
         "start_offset": 12,
         "end_offset": 16,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 2
      }
   ]
}
```

Also not sure about your ES version but my requires boolean values `true` and `false` to be lowercased.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that. True and False here are python's booleans which are translated to lowercase strings when sent to elasticsearch.

Comment: @AnimeshPandey fair enough :-)